# How to build GDAL 3.2.0 with VS 2019

Tags: gdal, visual-studio

I just can't get the latest GDAL release running with Visual Studio 2019.
Creating the VS project is no problem. Pretty straight forward. But when I try to build the project in VS in fails and gives me this error:

```
PROJ_INCLUDE should be defined. PROJ >= 6 is a required dependency
```

Of course I found this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600419/error-building-gdal-proj-include-should-be-defined-proj-6-is-a-required-dep

But that doesn't solve the problem. I tried downloading proj with OSGeo4w and I modified the `nmake.opt` file accordingly.

I tried every link I could find on google but with no luck. The GDAL community seems to be aware of that but maybe just don't care?

What can I do? Or do I have to use an older GDAL 2.x version (which seems to work) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use VS2019 16.8.3 and added a `nmake.local` file with:

```
# nmake.local
# see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600419/error-building-gdal-proj-include-should-be-defined-proj-6-is-a-required-dep
#####################################################################################

PROJ_INCLUDE = -IE:\Repos\proj-6.3.2\src
PROJ_LIBRARY =   C:\OSGeo4W64\lib\proj.lib
```

Only 2 warnings:

```
1>gdal_version.h(25): warning RC4011: identifier truncated to 'DO_NOT_DEFINE_GDAL_RELEASE_DATE'
1>gdal_version.h(25): warning RC4011: identifier truncated to 'DO_NOT_DEFINE_GDAL_RELEASE_DATE'
```

Perhaps a bug in `RC.EXE`. It truncates `DO_NOT_DEFINE_GDAL_RELEASE_DATE_AND_GDAL_RELEASE_NAME` to 31 chars!

Comment: I thought I had done that already. What I have done differently now is the following:
Download the ```proj.lib``` with ```OSGeo4W64``` installer.
Download the sourcecode for proj directly from their github (checking the "install-source" oprion in the 'OSGeo4W64' installer did not help at all.
And I had to add this flag to the ```nmake.local``` file as well:
```WIN64=YES```
Even tough I created the project withtin VS2019 in 64 Bit mode ..
But now it works!